# Various types of citing preference in AmE

Tags: grammar, american-english

In the following sentences, the italic ones do not sound idiomatic to me. Please have a look on them and let me know if I was not right:

> **1a** - I don’t like basketball. I prefer playing football.
>
> **2a** - I don’t like basketball. I prefer to play football.
>
> ***3a** - I don’t like basketball, I’d prefer playing football.*   ==> **Here we are talking a bout something in general, while the implication of this sentence is a specific occasion**.
>
> ***4a** - I don’t like basketball, I’d prefer to play football.*   ==> (**The same reason goes here**)
>
> ***5a** - I don’t like basketball, I’d rather play football.*   ==> (**The same reason goes here**)

---

> ***1b** - I like football, but I prefer playing basketball today.*   ===> (**Contrary to '1a', here we are talking about particular preference and whereas 'prefer' is used for general topics, then this sentence has a syntactic problem and sounds incorrect to me.**)
>
> ***2b** - I like football, but I prefer to play basketball today.*   ===> (**The same reason goes here**)
>
> **3b** - I like football, but I’d prefer playing basketball today.
>
> **4b** - I like football, but I’d prefer to play basketball today.
>
> **5b** - I like football, but I’d rather play basketball today.

PS. I would be grateful if the honorable AmE members could tell me if these are common in AE speech / written language. If yes, then which ones are the commonest ways?

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for myself, and there are many ways to answer this question; but my short answer is this:

**The only one that does not sound idiomatic (to me) is 3a.**

> ?3a - I don’t like basketball, I’d prefer playing football.

All the others sound idiomatic. Later, we'll see how to make 3a sound idiomatic.

I really dislike one or two-sentence contexts, because they rarely model anything from real-life discourse. They are abstractions which allegedly serve to exemplify a given condition, but this rarely works.

For instance, I find the most natural way to understand these statements is as an answer to some question (Q1) such as:

> Q1 - We're all going to play basketball, do you want to play (with us)?

Note that the use of *today* in such a context is not necessary, since it is understood.

And all the expressions with **would** in them are quite satisfactory, except 3a. So all the following work as an idiomatic answer to the question, with or without *today.* That is, you could add *today* to 4a and 5a, and remove *today* from 3a, 4a, 5a without a problem.

> 4a - I don’t like basketball, I’d prefer to play football.
>
> 5a - I don’t like basketball, I’d rather play football.
>
> 3b - I like football, but I’d prefer playing basketball today.
>
> 4b - I like football, but I’d prefer to play basketball today.
>
> 5b - I like football, but I’d rather play basketball today.

Those are all natural souding and quite satisfactory just the way they are.

I don't know what it is about the *would,* but it makes these statements perfectly natural as an answer to the proposed question. If I had to speculate, it might be the case that the structure is similar to a "fulfilled conditional," namely,

> 6 *[Since* you've given me the choice,] *I'd prefer* or *I'd rather*...

---

However, the statements *without* **would** also work as answers to the same question. But instead of stating it the manner of a "fulfilled conditional," they state it in the manner of what is always true:

> 1a - I don’t like basketball. I prefer playing football.
>
> 2a - I don’t like basketball. I prefer to play football.

The phrase *You know that* could easily go in front of both those sentences. Thus, showing that the first sentence is true all the time (given the contraints of one or two two sentence contexts).

> 1c - (You know that) I don’t like basketball. I prefer playing football.
>
> 2c - (You know that) I don’t like basketball. I prefer to play football.

The *prefer* phrase states what the person likes all the time., thus:

> 1d - (You know that) I don’t like basketball. What I like is playing football.
>
> 2d - (You know that) I don’t like basketball. What I like is to play football.

As for the B-Statements that did not sound idomatic to you, they are just fine

> 1b - I like football, but I prefer playing basketball today.
>
> 2b - I like football, but I prefer to play basketball today.

They are quite satisfactory, absolutely no problem. They sound perfectly natural, with or without *You know that* in front of them. Since you included *today* with them, they especially fit as an answer to the proposed question.

In other words, I do not agree that **whereas 'prefer' is used for general topics**

---

Now for the odd phrase out.

First let's restate the question:

> Q1 - We're all going to play basketball, do you want to play (with us)?

and the problem child:

> ?3a - I don’t like basketball, I’d prefer playing football.

Let's try *you know that:*

> ?3c - (You know that) I don’t like basketball, I’d prefer playing football.

Hmm. Not much better (to me).

What about the d-form without *you know that:*

> 3d - I don’t like basketball, What I like is playing football.

That works.

I think 3a is probably normal and idiomatic for some people. But to me, it cries out to be expressed as in 3d, above, or as in

> 3e - I don’t like basketball, I’d prefer playing football *today.* (specific)
>
> 3f - I don't like basketball, I'd prefer playing football *anyday.* (general)

Or use an explicit comparison:

> 3g - I don't like basketball. I'd prefer playing football to basketball (today/anyday).

Comment: Thank you very much for being of this great help. Are you online? May I ask you some more questions?

Comment: You can ask, but I'm not an expert. And I probably won't be able to answer right away. My answer is just one way to think about the subject. And I usually prefer language-in-context to abstract rules.